What's wrong with this solution?
While looking through a high school calculus test, I came across a question I didn't know how to solve (using only high school calculus). The question was along the lines of:

What is the volume of the shape created by taking the region of the $xy$-plane bounded by $y=x^2$, $y=0$, and $x=2$, and revolving it about the $y$-axis?

The solution I came up with was as follows:

We can imagine that the volume of the 3D shape created (let's call it
$A$) is some fraction of the cylinder sitting on the origin of radius
$2$ and height $4$ (call this $C$). We can easily find the volume of
the cylinder, so if we know the ratio between these two volumes we can
find the volume of shape $A$.
To find this ratio, look at the area occupied by each shape in the
$xy$-plane. We can calculate the area of the bounded region in the
$xy$ plane using integration, and the area of occupied by the cylinder
is just a rectangle and simple to calculate.
Since both 3D shapes are created by taking the slices of the $xy$-plane we've measured and revolving them about the $y$-axis, the ratio of their volumes should be proportional to the ratio of their areas.

I'm assuming this solution didn't work because proportions don't translate across dimensions (area to volume, etc.) but I'm looking for a more intuitive/visual explanation as to why this solution doesn't work, since it visually seems to make sense to me.

Points for cleverness, but a few examples should convince you that your core idea is wrong.  say the cyclinder is obtained by rotating the unit square in the first quadrant.  Now consider the cone generated by rotating half of that, namely the triangle wither vertices at $(0,0), (0,1), (1,1)$.  The cone hasn't got half the volume of the cylinder.

This is a totally standard high school calculus problem. Use either the method of cross-sections (which will be washers here) or the method of cylindrical shells.

Your shape can be approximated by a union of cylindrical annuli, of circumference $2\pi x$, thickness $dx$ and height $x^2$, giving a volume of $$V=\int_0^2 (2\pi x)x^2dx=8\pi.$$

Below is  something like the shapes you are looking at: i.e. what remains if you remove part of a paraboloid from a cylinder.  Your attempted calculation using 2D is based on what remains if you remove part of a parabola from a rectangle.
In both cases you are largely left with the outer part.  But in your 2D version you are ignoring the crucial point that a greater part of a cylinder is further away from its vertical axis (e.g. three quarters of the cylinder is more than halfway from the central axis to the outside) than is the case for a rectangle (only half of the rectangle is more than halfway from the vertical axis to the outside).
So your translation from 3D to 2D does not preserve proportions.


Let consider the simpler case of a cilinder obtained revolving about the $y-$axis the area bounded by $y=0$, $y=1$, $x=0$ and $x=2$ then the area in $xy$ plane from $x=0$ and $x=1$ and from $x=1$ and $x=2$  are equal ($A_1=A_2=1$) but volumes of internal cylinder ($V_1=\pi$) and volumes of external shell are different ($V_2=3\pi$).
The key point is that for a solid of revolution the volume is proportional not only to the area but also to its distance from the axis of revolution.
For more details, refer to Pappus's centroid theorem.

(image credits)

One way to see why your proportionality assumption is wrong is as follows: Your areas (a parabolic sector, a rectangle) sweep the corresponding volumes (paraboloid, cylinder) but the effective length of the "sweeping" is different. Namely, in the case of the cylinder, it is a circle of radius 1/2, given that the center of mass of the rectangle is at its center, while in the other case the center of mass and hence the sweeping "radius" is not 1/2 anymore, so the volumes are not in direct proportion to the areas. Notice that the center of mass of the parabolic sector is closer to the axis of rotation.

I suppose the region of the $x,y$ plane that you rotate in order to make the cylinder $C$ is the rectangle $R$ bounded by $y=0$, $y=4$, $x=0$, and $x=2$.
Instead of the shape bounded by $y=x^2$, $y=0$, and $x=2$, how about the shape bounded by $y=4$, $y=0$, $x=0$, and $x=1$? This has one half the area of the rectangle $R$; does the 3D volume it makes after rotation around the $y$ axis have half the volume of $C$?
Or consider the other half of the rectangle $R$, namely the rectangle bounded by
$y=4$, $y=0$, $x=1$, and $x=2$. When we rotate this around the $y$ axis, does it generate a shape with half the volume of $C$?
The volumes of these shapes are easy to compute without calculus if you just know how to compute the volume of a cylinder.
Now think about why the volumes generated by the left and right halves of rectangle $R$ are so different. It's the same reason why your method gives the wrong answer.
